# Incorrect margin and aligment Bootstrap + IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I have some problems with a site based on bootstrap css in IE (I was tested in IE9)

http://happyray.ru/

Why it looks so ugly?

http://joxi.ru/wMBGUdg5CbBoOgnMBxI

Comment: pull-left pull-right css class?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have an open tag somewhere in `head` section. While some browsers take care of this problem by just automatically closing the opened tag, IE won't close it for you. :)

I've just invastigated your page with IE8 and it's seems, that all the `head` stuff load inside `body` element. Please provide some raw html or just look for open tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your site triggers IE5 Quirksmode because of incorrect doctype/markup.
Please check
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhappyray.ru%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0
and fix the errors displayed.
Also try to use another doctype, for example `<!DOCTYPE html>`.
Then recheck.